# How can I write an update trigger to update the current table based on a value in another table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two tables, Table_A and Table_B. Table_A has a one-to-many relationship with Table_B.

After inserting a record in the child table (Table_B) I want to use a trigger to grab a value from a field in the parent table (Table_A) and update the currently inserted record in Table_B.

**Table_A**

```
PK|EmpID|MemID|Firstname|Lastname
----------------------------------
1 |1234 |AB123|John     | Doe
2 |5678 |CD456|Jane     | Smith
```

**Table_B**

```
PK|EmpID|MemID|Description
---------------------
1 |1234 |NULL |Finance
2 |1234 |NULL |IT
3 |5678 |NULL |Finance 
4 |5678 |NULL |Management
```

The trigger should grab the MemID value from Table_A and update it's corresponding value in Table_B where [Table_A].[EmpID] = [Table_B].[EmpID]. Of course after 4 inserts in Table_B the results should be as follows:

```
PK|EmpID|MemID|Description
---------------------
1 |1234 |AB123|Finance
2 |1234 |AB123|IT
3 |5678 |CD456|Finance 
4 |5678 |CD456|Management
```

I extensively searched other technical sites but can't seem to find one with this particular scenario. As a desperate move I have registered into this site and this would be my 1st post for help.

The following is my futile attempt at trying to create my 1st trigger in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgInsMemID
ON dbo.Table_B
AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Table_B
            SET MemID = 
                (SELECT MemID 
                FROM inserted i 
                JOIN dbo.Table_A c ON c.EmpID = i.EmpID)
            FROM dbo.Table_B b
            JOIN inserted i ON i.MemID = b.MemID
    END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Thank you for posting table structures, data, expected results, and your attempt so far.  It shows effort, and makes it much easier for the community to help you. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll want your update statement changed to look like this:

```
UPDATE b
SET b.MemId = a.MemId
FROM dbo.Table_B AS b
INNER JOIN Inserted AS i ON b.EmpId = i.EmpId
INNER JOIN dbo.Table_A AS a ON b.EmpId = a.EmpId
```

This will update only the records in b that were also in the `insterted` table. (first `INNER JOIN`)

It will then `INNER JOIN` into `Table_A` on `EmpId` to pull the proper `MemId` to update your records with.

Comment: Thank you for the help and yes, it did work perfectly when I inserted 100 records, and as expected of a trigger it did take a few seconds. I'm actually loading a text file via a C# program (implementing parallelism) that uses LINQ to SQL to write to DB and when I loaded 2 files the trigger was out of synch. But suffice to say, you have indeed answered my question perfectly based on my post. I'll just have to play around with triggers abit more, now that you have corrected my syntax. Thank you.

Comment: @Django Another option, if MemId doesn't have to be updated immediately is to run the update once after both of your files have been loaded into the database.  If you remove the `INNER JOIN inserted` line you would be able to update all of the Table_B records who match Table_A on EmpId with the MemId from Table_A.  You could also look at transactions to remove issues with syncing, but it will increase locking.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I appreciate your help in providing another option. Have tested both and I prefer the 1st one. Thank you once again.